# Python Selenium dynamic link error message

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download files from a work webpage (which is not public, unfortunately) and the download link is dynamic which changes for the file:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com_______________________________
```

My code is:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href='https')]").click()
```

the Error is

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@href='https')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Any help on what I'm missing would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath is wrong.

Instead of

```
//a[contains(@href='https')]
```

it should be

```
//a[contains(@href,'https')]
```

While using `contains`, note that to use `,` not `=`

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, what you tried is not a valid XPATH expression for Selenium.
Try this one:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'https')]").click()
```